# Silverstripe losing connection to MySQL server requiring a restart

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, silverstripe

Firstly please apologies for how vague this post may be but I'm completely at a loss as to what could be occurring here.

I've been having an issue with a site I've developed for a client where it seemingly, randomly loses connection to the MySQL server and requires a reboot of the server for the site to become available again.. I've a number of other SS sites in my portfolio and not a single other one has experienced this before.

The site can run for a few days or an hour or sometimes a couple of weeks before having this issue and I've not been able to pin down what actually triggers it, though it appears to be related to some kind of usage of the CMS. The client will report that it will lose the connection when he's trying to upload a photo or write a blog post. I've posted the error at the bottom of the post to not clutter things.

Thinking it was an issue with the server set up, I set up a brand new digital ocean droplet and migrated the site over to there, but the issue remains so it leads me to believe it's something within the framework or my site config (old server was running on CentOs and the new one is Ubuntu).

This is the only site I have set up using composer. A novice to composer, I followed the instructions on the SS site to achieve this. My composer.json is below. Does it look like I have any issues here?:

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.1.6",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.1.6",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "*",
        "silverstripe/blog": "dev-master",
        "undefinedoffset/sortablegridfield": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600  
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I've not made any changes to the core. Nothing unusual in there but my _config.php is:

```
<?php

global $project;
$project = 'mysite';

global $databaseConfig;
$databaseConfig = array(
    "type" => 'MySQLDatabase',
    "server" => 'localhost',
    "username" => 'root',
    "password" => 'xxxxxx',
    "database" => 'mysite',
    "path" => '',
);

// Set the site locale
i18n::set_locale('en_US');
Director::set_environment_type('dev');
Security::setDefaultAdmin("fraser","xxxxxxx");
```

Can anyone think of any reason why the connection would be dropping to the MySQL server? Is there anything else I should check? Do you need any more information from me?

```
[Warning] mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

GET /

Line 68 in /var/www/mysite/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php

Source

59   *  - password: The password to log on with
60   *  - database: The database to connect to
61   *  - timezone: (optional) The timezone offset. For example: +12:00, "Pacific/Auckland", or "SYSTEM"
62   */
63  public function __construct($parameters) {
64      if(!empty($parameters['port'])) {
65          $this->dbConn = new MySQLi($parameters['server'], $parameters['username'], $parameters['password'],
66              '', $parameters['port']);
67      } else {
68          $this->dbConn = new MySQLi($parameters['server'], $parameters['username'], $parameters['password']);
69      }
70 
71      if($this->dbConn->connect_error) {
72          $this->databaseError("Couldn't connect to MySQL database | " . $this->dbConn->connect_error);
73      }
74      
Trace

mysqli->mysqli(<filtered>,<filtered>,<filtered>) 
MySQLDatabase.php:68
MySQLDatabase->__construct(Array) 
DB.php:174
DB::connect(<filtered>) 
main.php:127
{closure}(ErrorControlChain) 
call_user_func(Closure,ErrorControlChain) 
ErrorControlChain.php:125
ErrorControlChain->step() 
ErrorControlChain.php:117
ErrorControlChain->execute() 
main.php:154
require_once(/var/www/mysite/framework/main.php) 
index.php:65
[User Error] Couldn't connect to MySQL database | Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

GET /

Line 598 in /var/www/mysite/framework/model/MySQLDatabase.php

Source

589     }
590 
591     public function databaseError($msg, $errorLevel = E_USER_ERROR) {
592         // try to extract and format query
593         if(preg_match('/Couldn\'t run query: ([^\|]*)\|\s*(.*)/', $msg, $matches)) {
594             $formatter = new SQLFormatter();
595             $msg = "Couldn't run query: \n" . $formatter->formatPlain($matches[1]) . "\n\n" . $matches[2];
596         }
597 
598         user_error($msg, $errorLevel);
599     }
600 
601     /**
602      * Return a boolean type-formatted string
603      *
604      * @param array $values Contains a tokenised list of info about this data type
Trace

Couldn't connect to MySQL database | Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) 
MySQLDatabase.php:598
MySQLDatabase->databaseError(Couldn't connect to MySQL database | Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)) 
MySQLDatabase.php:72
MySQLDatabase->__construct(Array) 
DB.php:174
DB::connect(<filtered>) 
main.php:127
{closure}(ErrorControlChain) 
call_user_func(Closure,ErrorControlChain) 
ErrorControlChain.php:125
ErrorControlChain->step() 
ErrorControlChain.php:117
ErrorControlChain->execute() 
main.php:154
require_once(/var/www/mysite/framework/main.php) 
index.php:65
```

Comment: Is there a mysql user "root" for "127.0.0.1" in your DB? I see in the config you use "localhost", the error is for "127.0.0.1" which seems odd.
It could also be some firewall problem?
The composer.json looks fine, though you can remove the "themes/simple"  entry, if you use another theme for your site.

Comment: @wmk There is a user for it, yes. The site works fine when I reboot the server and then it'll just sprout that error seemingly out of nowhere

Comment: Perhaps a bad MySQL install? I don't think the issue is with Silverstripe itself. Try reinstalling MySQL?

Comment: Have tried a fresh server build completely. One was using Maria DB, the other was using standard MySQL. Problem exists in both environments

Comment: What is the PHP, MySQL and Silverstripe versions (include minor revisions please)?

Comment: Have you checked that the server is not running out of resources that causes the mysql server to crash first.  Install munin or similar to the server to keep track on the resource usage.